# Weight Loss with Hyperthyroidism

Tags: weight-loss

I am over-weight, and have to loose at least 18 pounds. Despite my efforts, which I admit are not very consistent, I have not been able to make much of a difference. My doctor tells me that this could be due to my hyperthyroidism issues as well.

Is there anyway I can speed up the process?

Comment: Have you worked with a registered dietician to address your diet?  Given that you have hyperthyroidism you should have individualized diet instruction imo.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you have hyperthyroidism? There are 10 people claiming the condition for everyone who actually has a professional diagnosis... Calculate your actual calorie need and be super-strict about eating below it, do the math and read up on the math if you need to. Weight yourself every day and plot the numbers to see if there's a trend.

Comment: Provide more information about what you've tried.

Comment: I have a friend who had hyperthyroidism (not anymore, he's had his thyroid removed), but he's always been quite fit.

Answer (score 1):

The diet is the most important thing when losing weight, -even if you do loads of exercise every week -, if your diet isn't properly fixed then you will probably just gain muscle but not burn a lot of fat.

The best way to burn fat, is to do a combination of both aerobic (i.e. running) and anaerobic (i.e. weight lifting) exercise. Doing both types of exercise a few times per week will result in muscle gain and a higher weight loss.

As a side note: many people don't do weight lifting because their worried that they may become excessively bulky and muscular. That will only happen if you either take steroids or weight lift in excess, usually it will just give you a toned look.

Hope that helps, best of luck.

Comment: ***...many people don't do weight lifting because their worried that they may become excessively bulky and muscular.*** I think a lot of people don't do weight lifting because they're lazy and want the easy way out ***without realizing that weightlifting with cardio is the best combination to stay fit as well as perform better*** :).